# Import custom font in jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm developing an aplication that generates a PDF using Jasper. To do this I have a custom font that I generate in Jasper but the problem is I can't put this working. Every time that I try to generate the document gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font "reportFonts" is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

I'm on IntelliJ and I already setup the font jar in the project path like the this

[image]

And the library looks like this

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `reportFonts` font at fonts description (at *jar* file)?

Comment: yes. If I setup this into the sdk everything works, but hen I need everything packed in the same jar to distribute

Comment: For example, you can make the uber jar  - font extensions would work ok